# Opacity mask from vector drawing for phone sequence in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, effects, transitions

I am new to Premiere Pro and am making a sequence with three puppets talking on the phone, joined from different shots. I want a "scissor saw" separating them when they are talking and that separation moving in and out as puppets enter or exit the scene. For example, the sequence starts with one puppet in the whole screen and then the scissor saw enters from the right along with the second puppet.

Here is my vector drawing of the scissor saw; the text has the action for the puppets with time flowing down:

[image: schematics for scissor saw with puppet action]

The [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/how-to/create-clip-masks.html) shows how to create ellipse, 4-point polygon, and Bezier masks on a clip. What I would like, though, is to use a vector or bitmap drawing as a bitmask on a clip so a puppet is showing on the left and the right is transparent for the puppet on the other clip. This way, I am sure that the bitmask is aligned with the scissor saw and that I can smoothly transition the scissor saw drawing between clips, as that drawing is associated with the clip of puppet 2 when that puppet enters and then with the clip of puppet 1 when that puppet leaves.

How can I assign bitmasks to a clip on Premiere Pro?